# Remove a character at a specified position in Apex

Tags: apex, string

How can I remove a character at a specified position in Apex in String?

Comment: Build a new string with everything before and everything after the character you don't want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a generic function, you can write this:

```
static string removeChar(String source, Integer index) {
    return source.left(index)+source.right(source.length()-index-1);
}
```

This just removes the one character specified by index.

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to convert it into char array, remove the character and convert back into a string.

```
String oldName ='Pranay';
Integer [] nameArray =oldName.getChars();
nameArray.remove(3);
String newName = String.fromCharArray(nameArray);
System.debug(oldName); //prints Pranay
System.debug(newName); //prints Praay
```

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can use mid for that.

```
String s1 = 'abcde';
system.debug(s1.mid(0,3) + s1.mid(4,100));
```

You will remove the char in the position 4 in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, another approach can be using substring.

```
static string removeChar(String source, Integer index) {
    return source.substring(0,index)+source.substring(index+1);
}
```